# get multiple row result into single row but with different column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I achieve the following in oracle without creating a stored procedure?

```
Data Set:

question_id    element_id
1              7
1              8
2              9
3              10
3              11
3              12
Desired Result:

question_id    element_id1  element_id2 element_id3
1              7               8          null
2              9               null       null
3              10              11          12
```

Comment: Could you provide your table structures

Comment: Can we assume that each `question_id` appears at most 3 times in the data set (or some other fixed number that is determined at compile time)?  Or do you need the number of columns in the result set to change based on the data in the table?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivot query but you need a column for the pivot.  That is where `row_number()` comes in:

```
select question_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then element_id end) as element_id1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then element_id end) as element_id2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then element_id end) as element_id3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by question_id order by element_id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by question_id;
```

Comment: exact answer for me....thank you...